# Java inheritance: Can I access the constructor with parameters in super class?

Tags: java

Let say I have a class:

```
package inheritanceexample;

public class SuperClass {

    public SuperClass() {
        System.out.println("super class constructor 1");
    }

    public SuperClass(int a) {
        System.out.println("super class constructor 2");
    }

    public SuperClass(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("super class constructor 3");
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    public SubClass() {
        System.out.println("sub class constructor 1");
    }

    public SubClass(int a) {
        System.out.println("sub class constructor 2");
    }

    public SubClass(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("sub class constructor 3");
    }
}

public class SubClass1 extends SubClass {

    public SubClass1(int a) {
        super(a);
        System.out.println("sub class 1 constructor 1");
    }
}
```

How can I access the constructor in super class with parameters, lets say the constructor `SuperClass(int a)`, if I'm going to access it in the `SubClass1` which `extends SubClass` because when I put `super(int a)` in the `SubClass1` it only accesses or executes the constructor in the subclass which it extends. Can I access the constructor in super class with parameters directly in `SubClass1`?

Comment: Just call it from the extending constructor. Like super(), super(a), and super(a,b)

Comment: Please use the standard conventions for class names, where the first character is uppercased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot skip levels of the constructor: if the class in the middle (i.e. `subclass`) does not expose a constructor that calls a particular constructor of `superclass`, subclasses of `subclass` no longer have an ability to access these constructors.

The `super` keyword lets you jump exactly one level up; jumping through multiple levels is not allowed.

This rule makes perfect sense, though: to `subclass1` the fact that `subclass` extends `superClass` is an implementation detail. Letting `subclass1` call through to a constructor of `superClass` over the head of its own superclass would break encapsulation of `superclass`.

Comment: In other words, what you need to do is add the `super` call to the subclass constructor that you'd call via the `super` call in the sub-subclass.